# Get IP address with JavaScript - how to use globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `$.getJSON()` on an IP address API. I need to access its value later in my script (outside of the `.getJSON()` call. I haven't dusted off the coding boots for a bit, so any help is appreciated:

```
function getIPAddy() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=?",
    function(json) {
      // works 
      console.log(json.ip)
      // doesn't work
      return json.ip;
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: $.getJSON returns a Promise. You'll have to use the Promise. See the linked duplicates.